# How to automatically duplicate copy contents of one folder to another folder on a different disk?

Tags: copy, disk

I have a folder in im c:/ drive (lets say C:\users\myname\python). Every time I create new files in that directory, is it possible to have those files automatically copy to a folder on my d: disk (d:\"magic briefcase").

The main reason I want to so this is that on my d: disk I have the "magic briefcase" of the sugarsync program set up. This lets me share the contents of that folder with my other computer in real time (which has the same "magic briefcase" folder).

since python is installed on my c: disk, I need to save my .py files on the the c disk, but of course "magic briefcase" folder is on my d: disk. So will be great to have the contents of the c: disk automatically forward to the d: disk.

Is this possible???

Thanks
Darren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mklink /J "D:\magic briefcase\python" C:\users\myname\python`
should do what you want, I think.
That creates a "junction" aka hardlink between the two directories. Essentially you have one directory that's accessible via two different paths. Add a file to one of them, and it just *is* in the other one - no copying needed. Ditto for deletes, edits, etc.

Comment: Hi Edward - part the way there. The new 'python" folder was created in "d:\magic briefcase\". The folder has the little black arrow on it to show that it is a link. However, when I click on the folder to open it I get this message:                                      

"D:Magic Briefcase\python refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer, or on a network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted. or that you are connected to the internet or your network, and then try again."

Comment: @Darren, which version of Windows are you on? And if you open a command prompt (cmd.exe, listed as Command Prompt under Start > Accessories), then `dir "D:\Magic Briefcase"`, what does the entry for the python directory say? It should be `date time <JUNCTION> python [C:\users\myname\python]`. Check the spelling carefully, and make sure all the backslashes are present and correct. And don't forget that any path containing spaces needs to be in double-quotes.

Comment: Following your instruction and looking in the directory using the command prompt, I realized my silly error. The c: pathway was showing that I had actually used "myname" in it, instead of actually putting my name in there - doh. Now it is working perfectly. I created and deleted some files to test, and awesome :-) Thank you Edward! I tried to vote you up, but it says I need 15 reputation before I can do that, but as soon as I get 25 reps I will. I wont forget, this was very helpful!